# Нужно вернуть объект Iterator типа Integer из метода принимающего числовой массив. Т.е. нужно применить паттерн Iterator внутри метода

Tags: java, итераторы

```
public static Iterator <Integer> someMethod (int [ ] array){
 @Override
 public boolean hasNext() {
  if (index < array.length) {
   return true;}
  throw new NoSuchElementException();}
            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    return array[index];
                }
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
        }
       return iterator;}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно вернуть объект Итератор для принятого числового массива